# Get timestamp from MongoDB ObjectId though PrestoDB

Tags: mongodb, presto, trino

I'm using PrestoDB to query some MongoDB collections. MongoDB has a `getTimestamp()` [method](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/ObjectId.getTimestamp/) to get the timestamp portion of an ObjectId. How can I get a similar timestamp on PrestoDB?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not implemented in Presto, but there is a PR: https://github.com/prestosql/presto/pull/3089

You can implement this with eg

```
@ScalarFunction("get_timestamp")
@SqlType(StandardTypes.TIMESTAMP_WITH_TIME_ZONE) // ObjectId's timestamp is a point in time
public static long getTimestamp(@SqlType("ObjectId") Slice value)
{
    int epochSeconds = new ObjectId(value.getBytes()).getTimestamp();
    return DateTimeEncoding.packDateTimeWithZone(TimeUnit.SECONDS.toMillis(epochSeconds), UTC_KEY);
}
```

-- add this in the https://github.com/prestosql/presto/blob/master/presto-mongodb/src/main/java/io/prestosql/plugin/mongodb/ObjectIdFunctions.java class

Comment: And the reverse operation: https://github.com/trinodb/trino/pull/8824